# TypeORM relationship: Only IDs instead of whole instances

Tags: foreign-keys, relationship, typeorm

According to the [documentation](https://typeorm.io/#/one-to-one-relations), in TypeORM a relationship is defined as follows: 
A user has exactly one profile.

```
import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, OneToOne, JoinColumn} from "typeorm";
import {Profile} from "./Profile";

@Entity()
export class User {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @OneToOne(type => Profile)
    @JoinColumn()
    profile: Profile;

}
```

**Issue**

When creating a new user, why do I have to pass a complete instance of the entity (**profile: Profile**) instead of - as usual - only one ID? Like this:

```
@OneToOne(type => Profile)
    @JoinColumn()
    profileId: number;
```

Isn't there another way?

This procedure causes a large, unnecessary overhead, if you have to make 4 queries for 4 foreign keys to get the corresponding instance instead of the ID.

I would be very grateful for help to get around this!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In TypeORM the navigation field (here `profile`) can be combined with the plain foreign key field (`profileId`). So you can write:

```ts
@Entity()
export class User {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @OneToOne(type => Profile)
    @JoinColumn()
    profile: Profile;

    @Column()
    profileId: number;

}
```

Then it's up to you if you update the relation with the entity object or only with the profile id.

Comment: Amazingly simple, but it works - thank you very much, that helps me a lot!

But that's not in the documentation, is it?
At this point, I find that TypeORM takes away too much control and does some things in the background that are not quite obvious and expectable.

Comment: It is mentioned [here](https://typeorm.io/#/relations-faq/how-to-use-relation-id-without-joining-relation) in a slightly different context. You are right with your concerns that TypeORM is abstracting/hiding a lot of things and the result is sometimes not foreseeable, but mostly reading the source code clarifies things.

Comment: You guys know anything about if I can have relationships with an Entity that has ID type String (varchar)??

Comment: What happens when the Profile is deleted? profileId is not nulled.