# TypeORM relation only gives back ids

Tags: javascript, typescript, orm, nestjs, typeorm

I am new to TypeORM so this might be a simple question but i've made two entities with a OneToMany and ManyToOne relation like so:

```js
@Entity('user')
export class UserEntity {
  // I left out other fields
  @OneToMany(
    () => ConfigurationEntity,
    (configuration) => configuration.createdBy,
    { nullable: true, cascade: true, eager: true },
  )
  createdConfigurations?: ConfigurationEntity[];
}
```

```js
@Entity('configurations')
export class ConfigurationEntity {
  @ManyToOne(() => UserEntity, (user) => user.createdConfigurations)
  createdBy: UserEntity;
}
```

When I create a configuration, I save it by adding a ConfigurationEntity to a UserEntity and then I save the UserEntity like so:

```js
async createConfiguration(configurationDto: ConfigurationDto, userEntity: UserEntity) {
    let configurationEntity = new ConfigurationEntity();
    configurationEntity.createdBy = userEntity;

    // here I set some other values of my configurationEntity which I left out
    // ....

    if (!userEntity.createdConfigurations) {
      userEntity.createdConfigurations = [];
    }
    userEntity.createdConfigurations.push(configurationEntity);
    await this.userRepository.save(userEntity);

    configurationEntity.createdBy = undefined;
    return configurationEntity;
  }
```

Everything seems fine and when I save it, it actually gets saved fine.
The problem I have is when I try to find a user and look at the createdConfigurations, I only have a list of the id's of the configurations. I would like to see the full ConfigurationEntity (without createdBy because of circular reference). How can I accomplish this?

Actual:

```js
{
  id: 1,
  createdConfigurations: [ { id: 3 }, { id: 4 } ]
}
```

Expected:

```js
{
  id: 1,
  createdConfigurations: [ { id: 3, brand: 'Mercedes', ... }, { id: 4, brand: 'Kia', ... } ]
}
```

Comment: Looks a bit similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59831159/typeorm-relationship-only-ids-instead-of-whole-instances and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65576551/typeorm-does-not-return-all-data

Comment: You have not defined any column named `brand` in `createdConfigurations` entity

Comment: @omidh I left that out because it wasn't really usefull for my problem but I do have a column brand (and much more).

Answer (score 1):

I found out what the issue was. It had to do with the eager option.
My configuration entity looked like this:

```js
@Entity('configurations')
export class ConfigurationEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @OneToOne(() => ConfigurationBasicInfoEntity, { cascade: true })
  @JoinColumn()
  basicInfo: ConfigurationBasicInfoEntity;

  @OneToOne(() => ConfigurationColorUpholsteryEntity, {
    cascade: true,
  })
  @JoinColumn()
  colorUpholsteryInfo: ConfigurationColorUpholsteryEntity;

  @OneToOne(() => ConfigurationFinanceEntity, { cascade: true })
  @JoinColumn()
  financeInfo: ConfigurationFinanceEntity;

  @OneToOne(() => ConfigurationContactEntity, { cascade: true })
  @JoinColumn()
  contactInfo: ConfigurationContactEntity;

  @ManyToOne(() => UserEntity, (user) => user.createdConfigurations)
  createdBy: UserEntity;
}
```

I had to add eager: true to the options of my entities to load them in like so:

```js
@Entity('configurations')
export class ConfigurationEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @OneToOne(() => ConfigurationBasicInfoEntity, { cascade: true, eager: true })
  @JoinColumn()
  basicInfo: ConfigurationBasicInfoEntity;

  @OneToOne(() => ConfigurationColorUpholsteryEntity, {
    cascade: true,
    eager: true,
  })
  @JoinColumn()
  colorUpholsteryInfo: ConfigurationColorUpholsteryEntity;

  @OneToOne(() => ConfigurationFinanceEntity, { cascade: true, eager: true })
  @JoinColumn()
  financeInfo: ConfigurationFinanceEntity;

  @OneToOne(() => ConfigurationContactEntity, { cascade: true, eager: true })
  @JoinColumn()
  contactInfo: ConfigurationContactEntity;

  @ManyToOne(() => UserEntity, (user) => user.createdConfigurations)
  createdBy: UserEntity;
}
```